# Apache 2.4 allow access to directory that is password protected

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm really struggling with the new way of doing this, 2.2 was easy, this what I have:

```
<Directory  /home/website/public_html/>    
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All

    AuthType Basic AuthName "Password Protected Area" AuthUserFile /home/.passwd

    <RequireAny>
        <RequireAll>
            Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^allowaccess/tothisdirectory/$# 
        </RequireAll>
        Require user someuser
    </RequireAny>

</Directory>
```

So the folder `allowaccess/tothisdirectory` is in public_html. The whole of public_html is successfully password protected but the rule to allow access to `allowaccess/tothisdirectory` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^allowaccess/tothisdirectory/$#
```

To

```
Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/allowaccess/tothisdirectory/*#
```

Has worked